# PHP Fwrite: How Write on a file in the last line without clean the all content of the document

Tags: php, mysql, linux, server

How Write on a file in the last line without clean the all content of the document:

```
if($query>9999){        

            $file = file_get_contents(' /home/server/public_html/.htaccess');
            $checklist = ".htacess";
            #deny from 210.126.173.80
            $sheriff = 'deny from '.$ip;
            #Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
            #$f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
            $f = fopen($checklist, $sheriff);
            fwrite($f,$file);
            fclose($f);         
        }
```

Comment: You can [append](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to a file. Or use the 'a' flag as append [mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: `file_put_contents('/home/server/.../file', $yourData, FILE_APPEND)`